# Is there a way to plot with 2 y values and one x

Tags: r

I want to make a plot which has two y values and I can't seem to be able to find any way to make it work I'd imagne the code would look something like this:

```
x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)
y1 = c(10,13,15,17,11)
y2 = c(5,7,8,3,5)

plot(x1, y1, y2)
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type
```

Comment: matplot() can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matplot` as *@jogo* suggested

```
matplot(x1, cbind(y1, y2), pch=c(1, 2), col=c(2, 3), xlab="x", ylab="y", main="My plot")
legend("topleft", legend=c("y1", "y2"), pch=c(1, 2), col=c(2, 3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For completeness the base R solution looks like this:

```
> x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)
> y1 = c(10,13,15,17,11)
> y2 = c(5,7,8,3,5)
> plot(x1, y1, type='l', ylim=c(0,20))
> lines(x1, y2, type='l', col='red')
```

Comment: Actually `matplot` is base R.^^

Comment: @jay.sf I was not aware of that, thanks for the clarification.